# Add x instances of a group in realtime

Tags: scripting, drivers, instances, dupli-groups

I want to add ***x*** (integer) instances of a group at ***f*(*x*)** location (eg: the 3rd instance is at (0,0.1 * 3,0)) where ***x*** can be controlled in real-time by the means of an empty or slider. This is similar to increasing the **count** in an array.

Comment: Is the 'in real-time controllable' x the number of instances or the variable x in the function?

Comment: @BertVdB They are the same. I've added the data type of ***x*** and an example of ***f(x)*** to reduce ambiguity.